# use of Plain Old Java Object class in Recycle View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am a beginner in android and wants to learn about RecyclerView,i saw many examples of static Recycle View some of them are using POJO class and some of them are not. can some one please explain me why they use POJO class in static recycle view and can suggest me source where i learn about same as on YouTube and on internet each developer uses different approach and its a bit confusing as a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POJOs` are useful because it's easy to bind them with layout elements. For example, there's a StockItem class, which contains the image, title and price fields. You create a recycler view element layout, which has `imageview` (for image) and 2 `textviews`. And then you just set image to `imageview` and set title and price to `textviews`. That's why pojo is used. [Here's the way](https://github.com/SergeiMikhailovskii/AndroidWeather/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mikhailovskii/weatherandroid/ui/adapter/WeatherAdapter.kt) how I work with `recyclerview`. Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: thakyou sir/mam you explain it in  a very simple way .can you also suggest from where i learn about recycler view and practice it .

Comment: @SergieMikhailovskii can i ask you one more question?

Comment: @Abhishek, yeah, u can ask here or create the new question